# Roll up summary criteria dropdown missing a few fields

Tags: roll-up-summary

I have an field that i am trying to create that will do a rollup count on opportunity products.

I have a field called "Product Code".  I want to use the rollup summary filter to say

"ProductCode" contains "INET"

however, ProductCode is not in the dropdown for my filter creation.  any ideas why?

as you can see productCode is a standard text field, so i dont know why its not in dropdown.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Its because ProductCode is actually formula field , thats pulling data on the basis of product selected on  your line item and you cant use formula fields in filter criteria.

Comment: What you can do is implement a workflow rule and copy over the value from product code to your custom field and use that one in your filter criteria.

Comment: @elijah - you should post your comment as the answer

Comment: @cropredy : Thanks for suggestion, I added it as answer

Answer (score 3):

Although the field is there but behind the scene, what is happening is Product Code is actually being calculated (ie formula field). (Just some unknown nuggets of Salesforce) which is pulling data from product selected on OLI  and as we know formula fields cant be used as filter criteria.

That's why its not appearing in your drop down.

Work around in your situation would be to create a *workflow rule* which will copy over the data from product code to your *custom text field*, which you can use in your roll up summary filter criteria.